# Is there a sharp distinction between particles and fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, wave-particle-duality

The quantisation of the electromagnetic field, proposed originally by Planck, blurs the distinction between particles and fields. 'Point' particles become fuzzy and subject to a wave equation. Also, the field takes on a particle-like nature (photon) which is otherwise classically represented as a continuum.

Then, if we have charged particles interacting through the electromagnetic field, is there an essential distinction between them?

Comment: Fields are sections of a fibre bundle, in a nutshell. Particles are irreducible representations thereof. Also, there is no photon in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @gented What do you think [single-photon sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source) generate and [single-photon detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_nanowire_single-photon_detector) detect?

Comment: @MarkMitchison I don't understand your comment (sarcasm probably?). My point was that the concept of photon arises in QFT and QM per se' doesn't involve them *at all*.

Comment: @gented Ah, I see what you meant. My comment was a genuine question, I thought you were saying that photons don't exist in quantum theory. Note that QFT is just quantum mechanics with fields as the degrees of freedom. It's a bit of an anachronism to refer specifically to single-particle non-relativistic quantum mechanics just as "quantum mechanics".

Comment: @MarkMitchison *"QFT is just quantum mechanics with fields as the degrees of freedom"* of course, and that makes **all** the difference :).

Comment: @gented Please elaborate; haven't had a course on QFT.

Comment: @expikx I suggest you make a more detailed question because the matter is long and complicated. Are you interested in knowing why field arise in quantum physics or why we need infinite degrees of freedom or technical details about connections on fibre bundles (all of this surely doesn't fit in just one answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'Point' particles become fuzzy and subject to a wave equation

One must not confuse the wave equations of classical mechanics with the wave equations of quantum mechanics. Mathematically they have sinusoidal solutions, but it is the variable assignments on the mathematics that  describe measurable physical quantities.

The classical solutions of Maxwell equations describe the variations of energy in space and time, the Poynting vector and the power carried by the classical electromagnetic waves.

The solutions of the quantum mechanical wave equations do not describe energy transfer and are chosen by the [postulates of quantum mechanics,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) , basic of which is that the wavefunction

[image: wavefunction]

It is the probability that waves, as seen in [the double slit experiments one particle at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles)

T[he same behavior is seen for photons .](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/)

Photons wavefunctions obey a [quantized maxwell's equation.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169)

> Then, if we have charged particles interacting through the electromagnetic field, is there an essential distinction between them?

At the particle level the classical electromagnetic field does not exist, it is interactions between photons and the rest of the particles that holds, and yes, there is a difference if a photon hits an electron or a proton for example. The study of scattering processes is explored by quantum field theory which is a meta level in calculations, based on the underlying quantum mechanical solutions of free particles. It leads to [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/feyns.html) which allow calculations for many body problems.

Using the tools of quantum field theory one can show that the classical [electromagnetic wave emerges from the underlying zillions of photons](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) , a quantum mechanical superposition of zillions of photons.

There is no essential distinction between particles, of which the photon is one, except their masses, spins and other quantum numbers. The photon is one of the elementary particles in the [standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

Comment: "The solutions of the quantum mechanical wave equations do not describe energy transfer" I do not agree. You can write a Schrödinger lagrangian and then obtain the Noether conservation laws of energy-momentum, charge and angular momentum for the Schrödinger wave function.

Comment: @my2cts These laws apply , but it is not the mass or the energy of the particles that is "waving", i.e. display sinusoidal behavior, but *the probability* of measuring a particle with given energy and momentum.

Comment: That is interpretation. The Noether conservation laws give us the distribution of energy etc. in a probabilistic sense. The same is true for Maxwell's equations. The difference is that the number of particles can be very large in the case of photons, which is what we call "classical".

Comment: @my2cts  Well,I think you are not thinking mainstream quantum mechanics, which depends on its postulates as  extra axioms, , not just the mathematics. https://www.google.gr/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=hyperphysics+quantum+mechanics+postulates&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij18TZpYnjAhUL2BoKHba0D50QBQgsKAA&biw=1366&bih=654 . how about single electron at a time?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles  . the energy-momentum would be a fourier transform of the wavefunction in space and time.

Comment: Noether's theorem and lagrangian mechanics are totally main stream. In what sense would my comment _not_ be main stream?

Comment: @my2cts  in refusing to understand that the quantum mechanics postlates/axioms interpret the wave equation differently, that it is a different framework., ruled by probabilities, not determinism.

Comment: This is a straw man comment, @annav. I did not make any such statements.

Comment: @my2cts  I am sorry if I misunderstood you, but you imply that conservation of energy and momentum given by Nothers theorem defines what energy/momentum do for individual interaction.. These conservations are true , but do not define the interaction, the probabilistic nature does.